# IIS Rewrite/Redirect rules for new multiple sub-domains hosted in single server

Tags: redirect, iis-8

I have websites running in IIS 8.5 in a single server.

```
http(s)://aaa.oldpage.com
http(s)://bbb.oldpage.com
http(s)://ccc.oldpage.com
```

I want them to redirect to

```
https://aaa.newpage.com
https://bbb.newpage.com
https://ccc.newpage.com
```

What would be the simplest way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Answer (score 0):

I removed the all the contents for the old site and added a 
**Web.config** to the root folder with a following redirect rule.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://aaa.newpage.com" exactDestination="true" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

now if user tried to access to the old page "http(s)://aaa.oldpage.com", it will redirect to the new page "https://aaa.newpage.com".